# QR decomposition Eigenvalues Eigenvectors

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

i am interested in finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors for any real matrix - large and not symmetric. i discovered that QR-algoritm is the best one. I have questions:

1) if A-matrix (real and not symmetric) is given, then $Q$-matrix can be found for example using Gramm-Schmidt orthogonalization procedure - if $A$ is real then in any case $Q$ is real too ... and $R$-matrix is real either (do I understand correctly ?)

2) if $A$ is real and not symmetric then the eigenvalues can be complex numbers. then, my question is - how to use $QR$-algorithm in order to find complex eigenvalues too ? (if the sequence $A_{(k+1)}=R_kQ_K$ will produce real matrices $A_{(k+1)}$ ?)

Comment: Good question. As an example, what happens if $A$ is already orthogonal?  In this case one $QR$ factorization has $Q=A$ and $R=I$, so the QR algorithm doesn't seem to do anything at all.  Have I made a mistake?

Comment: If the QR-algorithm is applied correctly, the matrix $A_n$ converges towards a matrix with $2\times 2$ diagonal blocks, from which the complex eigenvalues can easily be derived.

Comment: @felipeh You need shifts to make it work.